# Oracle Compound Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I realise this is a very basic question, but I have been stuck for three hours already and I could not find any hint from any help forum.

I started using PL SQL today and I immediately ran into the table mutation problem. I now want to write a compound trigger to get round the problem.

But I am not able to run the most basic compound trigger, not even when I copy the following code from Oracle's documentation pages.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005

I get the following error:

```
Error: ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 4071
```

when I run this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AverageUpdate FOR UPDATE OF Rating ON UserGame
COMPOUND TRIGGER;

BEFORE STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
NULL;
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
NULL;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
NULL;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
NULL;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END AverageUpdate;
/
```

Could anyone help me understand why?

Note: I am using Squirrel. I changed the default statement separator from ; to /

Comment: Remove semicolon after COMPOUND TRIGGER.

Comment: First, what version of Oracle are you using?  Compound triggers are a relatively new feature.  Second, if this is your first day using PL/SQL, it seems rather concerning that you're trying to work around a mutating table error.  Those errors almost always indicate that you are trying to do something that you shouldn't be doing in a trigger or that you have an underlying data model problem that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Ah yes, I had added the semi-colon out of desperation. It still does not work when I remove it.

Comment: Here is the version: BANNER
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.6.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
CORE 9.2.0.6.0 Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
Here is the version:

Comment: Justin, I think you raised the right question. I see that Oracle 9i was released in 2001... Compound statements were introduced with version 11g. That must be the reason why it does not work.

Comment: "*I immediately ran into the table mutation problem*" - very often (especially for people new to Oracle) this happens because of a misunderstanding on how **row level** triggers work. You don't usually need to `select` or `update` the table on which the trigger is fired because you can access all columns of the modified/inserted row directly. You should post a new question telling us what the *actual* problem is (and of course stop using a deprecated and  unsupported version of Oracle)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a choice. This is the version installed at my uni's labs. I will post a separate question to try to find a solution to my original problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you are running a very old version of Oracle (9.2.0.6 has been deprecated for quite a number of years) and compound triggers did not exist at that time.  In 9.2, you'd have to declare multiple triggers that worked together to work around the mutating trigger error.